# Check if still android device is in acceleration in a moving car using accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, motion

I have a scenario,
I have kept my android device in the car. Can i check if the car is moving using accelerometer.

Comment: No, when using accelerometer you must avoid all calculations. Then again... what makes you believe that what youre asking is possible?

Comment: Yes. Have you got a more specific question (making sure, I suggest, you distinguish between movement and acceleration and how you want the app to behave)?

Comment: Math tells me that this is not possible on a vanilla Android device (you can't get initial velocity using acceleration). Project Tango should be able to do what you  want, though!

Answer (score 0):

you may not be able and has nothing to do with maths or the system you choose. Inertial velocity cannot be measured at all. Without looking outside the car you cannot distinguish wether it is moving or not if speed is constant. The phone won´t be able on doing that with the accelerometer, maybe with the camera...

you may need two cameras, though, because you have to measure distances and triangulate where you are and where you´ve moved to in a time period. And what if the cameras fix a point on a plant or a tree that keep waving with the wind?

would not gps be better?